# How to generate a C++ installer with all files embeded in it?

Tags: c++, windows, copy, installation, dev-c++

I generated an executable with C++ that copies files from a folder to another one,
Is there a way to include the folder that I copy inside my program instead of having it on the disk ?

I'm not using Visual C++, only DevCPP on windows and I'm targetting only windows machines.

Thanks

Comment: There are many c++ setup frameworks out there... At least specify which platform you are after...

Comment: @DanielTrugman It's just for windows, I've seen some tutorials on how to do it with Visual C++, but I can't use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic option of most setup frameworks.

**Free Option: NSIS**

Use the example under [Simply install a file](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Simple_tutorials#Simply_install_a_file) to see how you can embed files into the installer, specify where to unpack them, etc.

**Paid Option: InstallShield**

See the [Basic MSI Project Tutorial](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/TutorialTop.htm) for more info

Comment: NSIS is perfect, is there a way to get the output as a code cpp or header file ?

Comment: @HichamZouarhi, NSIS generates an `msi` installer file, that you can then double click and run on your system.